# Apache ignite on AWS EC2

Tags: ignite

I'm using Apache ignite version 2.15.0 installed on EC2 instance

Here my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
     <property name="workDirectory" value="/opt/ignite/ignite-work-directory" />
     <property name="addressResolver">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
             <constructor-arg>
                 <map>
                     <entry key="aws_ec2_private_ip" value="aws_ec2_public_ip"/>
                 </map>
             </constructor-arg>
         </bean>
     </property>
      <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
      <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false" />
      <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
      <property name="includeEventTypes">
         <list>
            <!--Task execution events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />
            <!--Cache events-->
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
            <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />
         </list>
      </property>
      <property name="gridLogger">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.slf4j.Slf4jLogger" />
      </property>
      <property name="communicationSpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
            <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="1000" />
            <property name="messageQueueLimit" value="1024" />
         </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="discoverySpi">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
              <property name="ipFinder">
                  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                      <property name="addresses">
                          <list>
                              <value>aws_ec2_private_ip:47500..47509</value>
                          </list>
                      </property>
                  </bean>
              </property>
          </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

When I start the node everything is working pretty good; ignite node logs show the following:

```
[14:22:52] Ignite node started OK (id=8e723dea)
[14:22:52] Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=8e723dea, servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=8, offheap=6.2GB, heap=12.0GB]
```

So far so good. I configured also security group in order to accept all TCP communication from my own IP address.

Then I wrote this simple spring bean:

```
  @Bean
  public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setGridLogger(new Slf4jLogger());
    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    TcpDiscoveryIpFinder ipFinder = null;
    if (DeployMode.KUBERNETES.equals(deployMode)) {
      KubernetesConnectionConfiguration kubernetesConnectionConfiguration = new KubernetesConnectionConfiguration();
      kubernetesConnectionConfiguration.setNamespace(namespace);
      kubernetesConnectionConfiguration.setServiceName(serviceName);
      ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder(kubernetesConnectionConfiguration);
    } else if (DeployMode.DEVELOPMENT.equals(deployMode)) {

      ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
      ((TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder) ipFinder).setAddresses(Collections.singletonList(host));
      //ipFinder.registerAddresses(Arrays.asList(new InetSocketAddress(host, port)));
    }
    TcpCommunicationSpi tcpCommunicationSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
    tcpCommunicationSpi.setMessageQueueLimit(1024);
    tcpCommunicationSpi.setSlowClientQueueLimit(1000);
    tcpCommunicationSpi.setLocalAddress(host);
    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(tcpCommunicationSpi);
    TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
    CacheConfiguration<String, ObservationPatient> observationCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(
        "ObservationCache");
    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(observationCfg);
    return cfg;
  }
```

When I try to start a simple unit class, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectGateway@4a49919c, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@3e5b2630[Count = 1], stopping=false, clientPool=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectionClientPool@2941631f, nioSrvWrapper=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper@6130a6f5, stateProvider=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ClusterStateProvider@3fb0d9de]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:280) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.start(GridIoManager.java:490) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1764) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to initialize TCP server: /aws_ec2_public_ip
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.spiStart(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:769) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:277) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to bind to any port within range [startPort=47100, portRange=100, locHost=/52.29.131.117]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.resetNioServer(GridNioServerWrapper.java:962) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.spiStart(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:766) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    ... 145 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to initialize NIO selector.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.createSelector(GridNioServer.java:1054) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.<init>(GridNioServer.java:386) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.<init>(GridNioServer.java:110) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$Builder.build(GridNioServer.java:3898) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.GridNioServerWrapper.resetNioServer(GridNioServerWrapper.java:926) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    ... 146 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:556) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:301) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:89) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer.createSelector(GridNioServer.java:1038) ~[ignite-core-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    ... 150 common frames omitted
```

I tried the telnet on aws_ec2_public_ip 47100 and it works. I'm not able to solve this issue

Any good tip?

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is this line:

```
tcpCommunicationSpi.setLocalAddress(host);
```

Most likely you can just remove this line. It's normally used when your machine has multiple network addresses.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried also by removing it but still not working. What I saw is that from the node (ec2 server) TCP outbound communication to the client node (my laptop) is not enabled. Maybe this is the issue. Moreover I didn't understand if in the node i should put also the client node ip address (but I think it's not necessary)

Comment: Maybe try setting forceClientToServerConnections to true (https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/clustering/running-client-nodes-behind-nat#limitations)

Comment: I tried it also but not working. Since when I install all locally everything works pretty good, I think the issue is related to the outbound communication between ECS server and my laptop. Since I can't rule my company networking rules, I left the good idea to install on ECS (sadly); I'll try a shot when I deploy the whole solution on EKS cluster where I already installed an ignite clusters

Comment: Well just an update. I had to install locally the server node. When I deployed the application on the ECS after I correctly configured the ServiceAccount all works pretty good. I just need to understand, on ECS, how to enable some ignire modules (e.g. ml); it should be enough to list it in the deployment of the statefullset